# While read loop and command with file output

Tags: while-loop, output

I have run into an issue making a while loop (yes, I am new at this..).

I have a file $lines_to_find.txt, containing a list of names which I would like to find in another (large) file $file_to_search.fasta.
When the lines in lines_to_find.txt are found in file_to_search.fasta, the lines with search hits I would like to be printed to a new file: output_file.fasta.

So I have a command similar to grep, that takes the sequences (for that is whats in the large file), and prints them to a new file:

obigrep -D SEARCHWORD INPUTFILE.fasta > OUPUTFILE.fasta

Now I would like the searchword to be replaced with the file lines_to_find.txt, and each line should be read and matched to the file_to_search.fasta. Output should preferably be one file, containing the sequence-hits from all lines in file lines_to_find.txt.

I tried this:

> while read line
>
> do
>
> obigrep -D '$line' file_to_search.fasta >> outputfile.fasta
>
> done < lines_to_find.txt

But my outputfile just returns empty.

What am I doing wrong?
Am I just building the while read loop wrong?
Are there other ways to do it?

I'm open to all suggestions, and as I am new, please point out obvious begginer-flaws.

Comment: Which language are you programming in?

Comment: The obigreb command is python-based, if that answers your question?

Comment: I made it work, more or less just like above... Why it didn't in the first 10 tries, I don't know.